# Help evaluating residue with simple poles

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

I am having a bit of trouble evaluating $$\sum_{k=1}^3{
\rm Res}\left(\frac{\log(z)}{z^3+8};z_k\right)$$ where $z_1=2e^{i\pi}$, $z_2=2e^{i\pi/3}$ and $z_3=2e^{i5\pi/3}$. I know that each $z_k$ is a simple pole and, therefore, the residue should be equal to $$\sum_{k=1}^3\frac{\log(z_k)}{3z_k^{2}}$$ However, I can't seem to get the desired answer of $-\frac{\sqrt{3}\pi}{18}$. Help would be greatly appreciated!

**Note:** The back of my textbook says $${\rm Res}\left(\frac{\log(z)}{z^3+8};z_k\right)=\frac{-z_k\log(z_k)}{24}$$

Still, I don't see where this comes from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$${\rm Res}\left(\frac{\log z}{z^3+8}, z_k\right) = \frac{\log z}{3z^2}\bigg|_{z=z_k} = \frac{\log z_k}{3z_k^2} = -\frac{z_k \log z_k}{24} $$because $z_k^3 = -8$ for all $k$ (I multiplied both numerator and denominator by $z_k$).

---

Result: if $a$ is a simple pole of $f/g$, then ${\rm Res}(f(z)/g(z), a) = f(a)/g'(a)$.

Comment: Thank you! I'm still having a bit of trouble finding the residue. I can't seem to get the desired answer.

Comment: It is a direct application of the result I mentioned above. Make sure you're not doing arithmetic mistakes, only.

Comment: The answer should be $\sum_{k=1}^{3}\frac{-z_klog(z_k)}{24}$, correct? I can't seem to evaluate this without getting $log(2)$ as a part of the answer.

Comment: Wait.... I got it! Thank you! You were right. Arithmetic mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the branch of the log defined on $\mathbb{C}\setminus[0,\infty)$, $\log1=0$,
$$\begin{align}
\log (2\,e^{i\pi/3})&=\log 2+\frac{\pi}{3}\,i,\\
\log (2\,e^{i\pi})&=\log 2+\pi\,i,\\
\log (2\,e^{i5\pi/3})&=\log 2+\frac{5\,\pi}{3}\,i.
\end{align}$$
Since $z_1+z_2+z_3=0$, the $\log2$ contributions cancel, and
$$
\sum_{k=1}^3z_k\log z_k=2\,\pi\,i\Bigl(\frac{1}{3}e^{i\pi/3}+e^{i\pi}+\frac{5}{3}e^{i5\pi/3}\Bigr).
$$